# Jquery ajax does not stop on return false

Tags: jquery

I'm submitting a form via ajax and jquery :

```
$("#FormSubmitTexte").click(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();
                var form_texte_texte = tinyMCE.triggerSave();
        if($("#form_titre_texte").val()==="") //simple validation
        {
            $("#dialog").html(messages.saisir_titre);
                            $("#dialog").attr('title',messages.erreur);
                $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
                    buttons: {
                        "Ok": function() {
                          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                        }},
                                show: {effect: 'puff', duration: 100},
                                hide: {effect: 'puff', duration: 100}
                        });
            return false;
        }

if ($("#form_tags_texte").val() != "") {
            var matches = $("#form_tags_texte").val().match(/^[\w -ÀÁÂÃÄÅàáâãäåÒÓÔÕÖØòóôõöøÈÉÊËèéêëÇçÌÍÎÏìíîïÙÚÛÜùúûüÿÑñ,]+$/);
                    if (matches) {
                    }else{
                        $("#dialog").html(messages.tags_car);
                                $("#dialog").attr('title',messages.erreur);
                    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
                        buttons: {
                            "Ok": function() {
                              $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                            }},
                                    show: {effect: 'puff', duration: 100},
                                    hide: {effect: 'puff', duration: 100}
                            });
                return false;
                    }
                    var tableau_tags = $("#form_tags_texte").val().split(',');
                    $.each(tableau_tags, function(index, chunk) {
                        var taille = chunk.length;
                        if (taille > 20) {
                            $("#dialog").html(messages.tags_taille);
                                $("#dialog").attr('title',messages.erreur);
                    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
                        buttons: {
                            "Ok": function() {
                              $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                            }},
                                    show: {effect: 'puff', duration: 100},
                                    hide: {effect: 'puff', duration: 100}
                            });
                return false;
                        }
                    });
                }


        var myData = {titre : $("#form_titre_texte").val(), billet : $("#form_texte_texte").val(), tags_texte : $("#form_tags_texte").val()}
                var tinymce_editor_id = 'form_texte_texte';
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST", // HTTP method POST or GET
            url: "texte", //Where to make Ajax calls
            dataType:"text", // Data type, HTML, json etc.
            data:myData, //post variables
            success:function(response){
            $("#responds").before(response);
            $("#form_titre_texte").val(''); 
            $("#form_tags_texte").val('');
                        tinymce.get(tinymce_editor_id).setContent('');
                        //$.getScript("include/ajax_save_billets.js");
            },
            error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                alert(thrownError); //throw any errors
            }
        });
```

All controls are working correctly when return false, excepted the one which checks the size of the element (if (taille > 20) );
I don't understand why... Can you see something wrong in this code please?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its Returning False for the each Function....U need to put return false outside

```
var isValid=true;
    $.each(tableau_tags, function(index, chunk) {
      if (taille > 20) {
       //do something
       isValid=false;
      }
    }
    if(!isValid)
    {
     return isValid
    }
```

something like that will work

Comment: Thanks. Now it stops when it's wrong, but if it's right, it doesn't execute the ajax request...

Comment: Ok, got it! variable declaration was missing (isValid=true) before the loop. Thnks for your help!